# Basic Deep Copy, Java

Tags: java, copy

Okay, so i know there is a million questions out there on deep copy but i still have a hard time understanding because there is all this talk about cloning and serialization and what not. When making a deep copy of a String[] array is this how you would do it in a very simple way? without validating.

```
public String[] copyString(String[] others)
  {
    String[] copy = new String[others.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < others.length; i++)
    {
      copy[i] = others[i];
    }

    return copy;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When making a deep copy of a String[] array is this how you would do it in a very simple way?

Yes.

You need to

1. allocate a new object
2. deep-copy the contents from the source object

and that's exactly what your method does.

Note that this only works because `String` is immutable, otherwise you would be performing a shallow copy of the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use `Arrays.copyOf(others,others.length)` for a deep copy.